# Loading resources from another project?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xna, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to load an XML file from a separate project; One of these projects is a game engine, which calls the XML document reader and takes in a path specifying the relative directory to the file.

**From Engine**

```
XDocument doc;

            try
            {
                Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path);

                doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
            }
            catch
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            }
```

**From the other project**

```
string filePath = "Test.xml";

Npc npc = new Npc("somename", 2,filePath);
```

`Test.xml` resides in the other project's root directory. The `Npc` constructor makes a call to a `Statistics` object constructor, which then calls the method which loads the `XDocument`. As this is happening, the `filePath` is simply passed downward through the layers.

I've looked at [this](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2009/03/different-ways-to-access-xml-data-in.html), and tried the embedded resource example, which is ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish, and it didn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong, here?

**Update**

I changed `Text.xml` to `Chronos.Text.xml`, as that is where the file resides. In my debugger, I see that the stream simply returns null when I use that as a path:

```
try
{
    Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Chronos.Test.xml"); //returns null

    doc = XDocument.Load(stream); //Exception thrown
}
catch
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(path); //File not found
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embeded resources are embeded directly in the executable. `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()` is trying to open a stream on the embeded resource, what you should be providing is the resource name in the following format `AssemblyDefaultNamespace.Directory.Filename`.

If you are trying to open an XML file from another directory, you will have to provide the **full** path to `XDocument.Load()`, or a path relative from your current project output directory pointing to that other directory.

Another solution would be to copy the data from the other project into your project and specify that you want the file to be copied to your output directory.

Comment: Is there such a thing as AssemblyDefaultNamespace? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Right click your project in the tree, select `properties`. `Application` tab, there is an option on the top right called `Default namespace`.

Comment: I updated my answer: unfortunately, all I receive is null in the process. Is there anything else I can do to modify the query?

Comment: Make sure you added the default namespace before the directory name.